# Update callback of API defined property not called on keyframed property

Tags: python, blender-internal-render-engine

I have created a custom property (NeighborDistance). When I keyframed the property the update function is not called back. Is there any way to get the changed value each time for a new keyframe. Could anyone please guide me in this aspect. Thank you in advance.

```
def change(self, context):
    scne = context.object
    print("hello")


def initSceneProperties(scn):
    bpy.types.Object.neighBor = FloatProperty(
        name = "Float", max = 1.0,
        update = change)
    scn['neighBor'] = 0.7
    return
initSceneProperties(bpy.context.scene)

class UIPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Maneuvers"
    bl_space_type = "PROPERTIES"
    bl_region_type = "WINDOW"
    bl_context = "object"
    def draw(self, context):
        #global g
        layout = self.layout
        scn = context.object
        col.prop(scn, "neighBor", text="NeighborDistance")

if __name__ == "__main__":  # only for live edit.
    bpy.utils.register_module(__name__)
```

Comment: Yep that's right, keyframes / drivers etc  wont fire an update.  Only changing the prop value via the UI or code will.  Would get out of using `scn["prop"]` to set the default value of your property, use the `default=0.7` argument of the property definition. Since the scripts using this init approach, restricted context on registering addons has been introduced, during which time the scene instance is None.

Comment: @batFINGER: Thank you for the response. I understand the default value..but how to access the custom property on the keyframe change...Could tell me about that instead of using update ..

Comment: Do you want to run code each time you add a keyframe in UI? or ?